# How to place multiple figures at the left and caption at the RHS

Tags: captions

Please correct my code so that I can get the figures at the left side and caption at the right side.

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{float,subfigure}
        \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
        \usepackage{sidecap} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[b]
    \sidecaption
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{n1.eps}\\  
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{n2.eps}\\   
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{n3.eps}
    \end{subfigure}
            \caption{\small (Color online) Graphical illustration for $\rho =0.2$.}
            \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of exactly what you want (e.g. one caption per image? subfigures?) But the side-by-side effect can be achieved for example with minipages:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
  \begin{minipage}[c]{7cm}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{}\\  
    \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{}\\   
    \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2.5cm]{}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
    \caption{\small (Color online) Graphical illustration for $\rho =0.2$.}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Yes I need this. Thank you very much. I want to use sidecap. I need the help.